# Capturing the drop values (not the drags) on bootstrap slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the BootStrap Slider mentioned here :

http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/

I seem to have run into a rather strange requirement. As users drag the slider, the change in the slider value can change and such change can be capture (as mentioned in the examples in the link above).

However, I want to capture only those values of the slider at which the user "rests" after a slider, (or drops after the drag). She slides, stops, slides back, stops, slides forth stops, and so on. I want to capture values only where she stops.

How can I do this ? Is there an event for a slider, that captures just the drop or the resting place ?

p.s. I have not included any detailed code because I use the code in those linked examples directly, Example 6 in particular, which mentions :

```
$("#ex6").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    $("#ex6SliderVal").text(slideEvt.value);
});
```

Comment: are you tryed .on("slideStop"... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#ex6").on("slideStop", function(slideEvt) {
    $("#ex6SliderVal").text(slideEvt.value);
});
```

More info [Here](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider#events)